# Django - Why I got Boolean result when I try to get data from the DB?

Tags: django

my view:

```
def add_word(request):
current_date = timezone.now()
english = request.POST.get("the_word_in_english", False)
hebrew = request.POST.get("the_word_in_hebrew", False)
context = request.POST.get("How_To_Remember", False)
name = request.POST.get("your_name", False)
Words.objects.create(pub_date=current_date, English_word=english, 
Hebrew_word=hebrew,How_To_Remember=context, Name=name)
return HttpResponseRedirect("/polls/")




{% if search %}
{% for item in word %}
<p> </p>
<b>{{ item.English_word }} </b>
<br>
{{ item.Hebrew_word }} <br>
{{ item.How_To_Remember}}
{{ item.Name }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
{%else%}
{{message}}
{%endif%}

        <form action ="add_word" method="post" class="from-inline">
        <input type="text" name="the_word_in_english" class="form-control mb-2 rm-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="איזו מילה תרצה להכניס למאגר?">
        <input type="text" name="the_word_in_hebrew" class="form-control mb-2 rm-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="?מה הפירוש למילה">
        <input type="text" name="context" class="form-control mb-2 rm-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="מה האסוציאציה שחשבת עליה?">
        <input type="text" name="your_name" class="form-control mb-2 rm-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="מה השם שלך?">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ">שליחה למאגר</button>

    </form>
```

All the field is gives regular result (string) just 'How_To_Remember' field give True/False result I tried to delete the migrations few times and the DB and create new one and I'm getting the same result every time..

if it try to write it like this

```
    context = request.POST.get("How_To_Remember")
```

I get other error of :
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_words.How_To_Remember

Comment: show your html form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a field in your form with the name="How_To_Remember"